# Calculation of Respiration Fluxes in Terrestrial Ecosystems Based on Total Respiration (RT)

Tags: photosynthesis, respiration, ecosystem, decomposition

**Overview**

Researchers have been studying a temperate grassland ecosystem with the view to understand it's current status with regard to carbon inputs and outputs and to identify whether the grassland is currently a sink or source of carbon.

**Investigation:**

The aim of this investigation is to calculate different respiration components within an ecosystem with the energy fluxes within a terrestrial ecosystem consisting of:

**Energy Fluxes**

1. GPP = Gross primary productivity
2. NPP = Net primary productivity
3. NEP = Net ecosystem production
4. NEE = Net ecosystem exchange
5. RT = Total respiration
6. RA = animal respiration
7. RS = soil respiration
8. RM = microbial respiration

**Query**

I have answered the questions below to the best of my ability but with much confusion (see calculations below).

Am I on the right track? Am I calculating these respiration components correctly?

If anyone is able to help here, your advice and input would be deeply appreciated.

Many thanks!

**Table 1: Flux values for temperature grassland**

[image]

**Respiration Components to be Calculated: My answers to the questions**

**1. Researchers measured the total ecosystem respiration (table 1;
    figure 1) as RT = 1300 g/Cm-2/yr-1. What is included in this total
    respiration?**

Rs and Ra are not to be included in this calculation because they are part of the heterotrophic respiration system and they cannot be added to plant respiration.

The respiration components incorporated into RT =1300 g/Cm-2/yr-1 is Rp = 800 g/Cm-2/yr-1 (plant respiration), leaving 500 g/Cm-2/yr-1 to
be designated to roots, shoots, and microbial respiration.

**2. The researchers measured soil respiration as  Rs = 900 g/Cm-2/yr-1 and estimat3e animal respiration above ground as RA = 50 g/Cm-2/yr-1. Calculate the respiration values for plant shoots (R,p-s), plant roots (R,p-r), and microbial activity (R,m).**

**Calculations for respiration components (Table 1; Figure 1)**

[image]

**Fig 1: Visual reprsentation of respiration fluxes**

[image]

Comment: Can you give your reasoning for why you did the calculations as you did?

Comment: Hi Oosaka, After doing some really dumb calculations, I went back to the drawing board and tried again. I think these calculations are much improved and all respiration fluxes add to 1300. Is this answer correct? Many thanks if you can offer any helpful advice. Thank you again, you have been wonderful!